# Reload environment variables without restarting Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, environment-variables

I use the function `Environ()` to get environment variables from a running Excel instance.
When a new variable is defined in the system, Excel won't know it until it doesn't get restarted.

My question is: **is there any way I can get the new value of the environment variables without need to restart Excel?**

The test case is:

- Windows search / System / Advanced system settings / Environment variables
- Open Microsoft Excel
- Define a new user variable, say `TESTING`, with value `Whatever`

[image]

- Run the following macro:

  ```
  Sub test()

      MsgBox "TESTING:" & Environ("TESTING")

  End Sub
  ```

... the variable is empty:

[image]

- Restart Microsoft Excel
- Re-run the same macro again: the variable is now loaded.

[image]

Comment: https://www.excelforum.com/excel-general/352028-changing-an-environment-variable.html

Comment: In that linked page `Function GetEnvironmentVar` may meet your needs.

Comment: Thanks @TimWilliams, will have a look.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```vb
Sub Test()

    MsgBox CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Environment("system").Item("testing")

End Sub
```

Comment: Love this approach, it's much cleaner than the previous one, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You need to subclass your excel window and intercept `wm_settingchange` messages that are sent from the control panel environment thing and `setx`.

This is VB.Net - lparam contains a pointer to a string saying `Environment`. It's up to you to work out what has changed.

```
Console.writeline(Marshal.PtrToStringUni(lparam))
```

Back to VB6/VBA

Here some code that hooks and unhooks and a winproc. You get Excel's hWnd from `excel.application` `hWnd` property.

```
Public Sub Hook()
   lpPrevWndProc = SetWindowLong(EditNote.gRtfHwnd, GWL_WNDPROC, _
   AddressOf gWindowProc)
End Sub
```

---

```
Public Sub Unhook()
   Dim temp As Long
   temp = SetWindowLong(EditNote.gRtfHwnd, GWL_WNDPROC, lpPrevWndProc)
End Sub
```

---

```
Public Function gWindowProc(ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal Msg As Long, _
                 ByVal wParam As Long, ByVal lParam As Long) As Long
   If Msg = WM_CONTEXTMENU Then
        If EditNote.mnuViewEditContextMenu.Checked Then EditNote.PopupMenu EditNote.mnuEdit
'        gWindowProc = CallWindowProc(lpPrevWndProc, hWnd, Msg, wParam, _
         lParam)
   Else ' Send all other messages to the default message handler
      gWindowProc = CallWindowProc(lpPrevWndProc, hwnd, Msg, wParam, _
         lParam)
   End If
End Function
```

Each application gets a copy of it's parent's environment memory block. A program cannot access another program's memory - so it's one way. Only Windows Explorer listens to this message. So an updated variable is only available in Windows Explorer and any new program started by explorer. Note: CMD does not listen for this.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to try to work around this and if it works, will accept the answer.

Comment: Just use `WScript.Shell`

Comment: Load a separate Excel instance, get the variables and close it?

Comment: @drgs Do you intend polling to find out when the change occurs. Start Excel everey 1 min????

Comment: @omegastripes Its when to know to do that.