# SQLite3 Refuses to Stay in PATH After Command Prompt is Closed

Tags: windows, cmd

I followed the instructions from this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w7-oOIRIhiQ.
I have successfully been able to add SQLite3 to my PATH.  The command

```
set PATH-%PATH%;C:\sqlite;
```

did not work, however, using the command `PATH`, copying my current path, and typing `PATH [my current path]C:\sqlite;`, I was able to put SQLite3 into my PATH.  Typing `sqlite3` worked.  Everything was perfectly fine until I closed the command prompt and opened it back up.  Then when I typed `sqlite3` it says

```
'sqlite3' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

***PLEASE HELP***

Comment: The easiest way to make your changes to the `PATH` "stick" is to edit environment variables from Windows.  [See here](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm) for an example of how to do this.

Comment: You need to use `setx` to make the change stick across processes.

Comment: `setx /?` from a command prompt.

Comment: Can you give me an example of setx?  I'm not that great with command prompt.  Thanks for the help though!

Comment: Right click *Start* button, *System*, *Advanced System Settings*, on *Advanced* tab click *Environmental Variables* button. Make it a user variable. User and system paths are added together so don't specify the `%path%`

Comment: sorry but when I right click the windows icon and hit System it goes to settings (Win10 just in case there's an operating system difference)

Comment: Should go to *Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\System*

Comment: Thanks!  I changed the name from some default name to sqlite.  But it still doesnt work.  The Apply button is also grayed out the entire time, however, I am computer admin.

Comment: ***YES IT DID DO SOMETHING*** Thank you so much catcat

Comment: I  rolled back your edit. It is not appropriate to add SOLVED to the title, or to add the solution to the question. If you've found a solution and want to share it with others, write an answer in the space below to do so. If you don't want to share that solution, delete the question using the link below the tags.

Comment: I didn't add the solution to the answer, but thank you for teaching me StackOverflow etiquette.  I won't say (SOLVED) again.

Comment: @get_scripted So what you do is write an answer on what worked for another person to follow. Then you mark your own answer as ANSWERED.

Comment: You can get some background on why its not simple here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54190384/reload-environment-variables-without-restarting-excel/54192101#54192101 and at the end of my answer here is a batch file that adds the folder path its in to the user path - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54203092/is-there-a-windows-equivalent-to-shlvl/54208357#54208357

Comment: N. B.: the `-` in `set PATH-%PATH%;C:\sqlite;` should be an `=`-sign, I guess... and I'd remove the trailing `;`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(ANSWER)
I found an answer (with the help of @catcat) 
Make sure you're an administrator.
Go to control panel, then System.
Hit Advanced Settings.
Under user variables click Path, then click edit.
Add `sqlite3` as the he name and `C:\sqlite` as the value.  Add it and hit done!

Test it with `sqlite3` in command prompt.